# Computer takes longer than usual to start than expected

Tags: boot, motherboard, desktop-computer, bootloader

My system is an MSI-G41M P26, Intel (R) Pentium and 2GB RAM.

The PC takes 10-15 mins to actually turn on with a beep. However when it's not started only the CPU and SMPS Fan spins after 10-15 mins the Manufacturer Logo Comes and then system boot is very slow.

I can't plug keyboard some times it says keyboard interface error and sometimes the system starts like a normal system starts

Comment: Are you sure it's worth the effort? First off, change the CMOS battery.

Comment: hi , i tried new cmos battery still same thing but this time the pc stucks in manufacturer's logo and never exits from that

Comment: take the ram out of the motherboard and swap locations with it. or place in different channels.

Comment: What's the specs on your DIMM modules, and your front-side bus (FSB) speed?  If you have 2 DIMM modules, try removing one (as a test), then try swapping them.  Check your BIOS settings to see if a "Quick Boot" option is available.  Disconnect any unnecessary USB devices to relax Plug-and-Play at startup.  And temporarily disconnect your case fans (not CPU fan) to relax power consumption during startup tests.

Comment: It's very old hardware. The correct thing to do is to begin replacing components one by one. Really anything except possibly the CPU could be at fault here.

Comment: hi,i replaced SMPS/PowerSupply , it now works . but when i plug hard disk it takes 10-15mins to get out of POST Screen and then hard disk is not detected in BIOS , sometimes hard disk gets detected and boots up